# split a string, breaking at a different character

Tags: javascript, parsing, split

I have the String:

```
Name01: Name02 - Project Name (Client) - Infos
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into:

```
Name01
Name02
Project Name
Client
Infos
```

Comment: ok lets say that your 'input' is a string - whats the output? is that an array? another string? split on new lines? split on spaces? but not for 'Project Name'?

Comment: This depends a bit on how much variation there's going to be in the input data.  Could "Project Name" include more than or fewer than two words? Or might any of the other fields ever need to include a space? Is there the possibility of ":" or "-" or "(" or ")" appearing as part of one of the names you need to capture, instead of just as a delimiter? Are there other regularities you can depend on being consistent, or irregularities you might need to work around?  You might have to do some defensive coding here to handle potentially weird input, rather than focusing on the "fastest" approach.

Comment: Further to Daniel, are the spaces required around the delimiters, or can it be, for example, `Name01:Name02-Project Name(Client)-Infos`  Can there be _more_ spaces? Are they always spaces never tabs? Can a dash appear in the project name? Can a colon appear in the Name01 and/or Name02 regions?

Comment: Thanks! Exact, it's a bit tricky.. The string come from the Tilte of a Google Calendar event. All users maintain the same roles with delimitaters but it can be something like : ⛔️Daniel: John Doe - American Airline( Coca-Cola ) - Red / son / Ext / 3 locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your string with a common character where ever you need. So that you can split on them. Try the following way:

```js
var str = "Name01: Name02 - Project Name (Client) - Infos"

str = str.replace(/[-()]/g,':').split(':');
str = str.filter(i => i.trim()).map(j => j.trim());

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Assuming none of `[-()]` or `:` will ever appear elsewhere in the string.

Comment: @StephenP, if none of those exists, `split()`will ignore those. The solution is based on the string provide...thanks

Comment: what about `.map(j => j.trim())` first, then `.filter(i => i)`? don't need to .trim() twice

Comment: @Sphinx, `map()` first then `filter()` will also work. Here `map()` trims the string and `filter()` removes the empty string from the array. but `map()` after `filter()` will decrease the number of iteration ....thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect but its simple:

```
const str = 'Name01: Name02 - Project Name (Client) - Infos';

const matches = str
  .replace(/[^\w\s+]/gi, '')
  .replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' ')
  .split(' ');

console.log(matches);
```

The issue here is keeping the space between `Project Name`.